Why does water vapor sometimes start to twirl above a pot of boiling water?
I have noticed that when I boil water in my kitchen the water vapor starts to twirl like a tornado. This question has been puzzling me for some time now and I haven't been able to figure it out. Even my teacher didn't really know the answer to my question so I'm asking if someone here can help me with my question. (My house does not have AC)

Finally a purely non-textbook question. I am sharing elementary physics knowledge.
Convection currents: When hot / warm light gas from below rises due to higher buoyant force than the gas particles on the above, the colder air from above tends to displace them.
This is caused by pressure difference. Say you have a cylindrical air column of water vapour that's less denser than air especially having higher kinetic energy. This is the one rising from inside your pressure cooker. Now, when some of the colder air particles from surrounding get into the light water vapours, they create a higher buoyant force on the vapours since the cold air is denser. This causes two thing: tendency of colder air to vertically displace the warm vapours below, and tendency of the cold air from sides to horizontally do the same. All this is because the pressure at the bottom of the cylindrical column on the above, cut by the entering cold air, is higher than at the top. Finally, change the concept of macroscopic cylinder to an atomic level, because the same goes for molecules.
I cannot say whether it must be shaped like tornado or not. Maybe that's a coincidence or that's the way physics works, since you see it frequently. However, a real tornado like feature would be created by the same thing along coastal areas, due to presence of more water vapour and wind, on large scale only. But since the major difference is the scale of formation, you shouldn't relate its formation with that of a real cyclone.

This doesn't seem to explain the twirling that the OP asked about. Are you suggesting that there is no actual rotation and only the shape of the vapor resembles a tornado?

@Bergi the "twirl" in my opinion, will come from a small difference in the temperature around the column of steam going up,

I think rotation isn't perfect to use here. Since the shape is created by vacuum driven pulling out of vapours from interior to exterior, it quite looks like the twirling tornado thing, but before further rotation, the vapours are gone off.
